# Div position for border to surround content

Tags: css, html, position

I have a content div where all the content is located.  this div has a border.  I would like to place things inside this div so that this div expands if the content inside is too big.  Should the items inside the content div be a "div" or a "p" and what css position should they have?

CSS:

```
#content{
position: relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
min-height: 200px;
width: 1000px;
padding: 0px 0px 80px 0px;
background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `width: 1000px;` it will prevent the content div from being any wider. I suspect you want `min-width: 1000px;` instead.

For internal content use `p` tags if you are creating paragraphs that only use inline html elements. If you are using block level elements then use `div` tags.

I can't say how you should style your internal elements because I know nothing about your design specs.

Answer (score 1):

Contents of the #content div can be either p or div elements its up to you. The #content div will expand to the height of its content either way unless you have elements inside #content with a `float` property.

If that is that case you can do something like below to make the #content div expand its height.

```
<div id="content">
    <div style="float:right; border:1px solid red; height:500px;"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

The important part here is the latest div with `clear:both` property which fixes the height of the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to use a DIV. If you use `height:auto;` that should make it expand based on your content. Also I think you can use `min-height:200px;` and `height:auto;` together; With that said. I also agree with mrtsherman, if you set a width or height to a specific pixel it is going to limit you to those constraints.